# WSO2 EI/ESB: For loop implementation

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, ei, wso2-esb

I want to implement a simple "**for loop**" in WSO2 Integration Studio.

For example:

I am implementing a bus-route API. Every bus has 10 different stops. I want to fetch the 10 stops from the back-end service. A normal for-loop for this would be:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    //back-end call
    <call>
       <endpoint>
          <http method="get" uri-template="https://backend.com/city+i"/>
       </endpoint>
    </call>
}
```

**NOTE:** In the above for loop, the back-end call has path parameter like city which should be iterated as city1, city2, city3,..... city9.

How do I implement this in WSO2 EI/ESB Integration Studio?

Comment: How are you storing the URLs for the backend calls? Based on that we can try to come up with an idea.

Comment: I have edited the for loop in the question and have also added a NOTE at bottom, please check. I'm not storing the URLs for backend calls anywhere. For backend calls, I'm using Call Mediator inside the http endpoint. Does this answer your doubt?

Answer (score 2):

One simple way would be to define a sample payload with the numbers inside an array and iterate through it. (This would work if the number of the iterations are predefined) For eg: [{"value" : 1},{"value" :2},{"value" : 3}, ...  ]

Or else you can write a custom class mediator and implement your logic.

Also there is a fun way to implement a while loop with the help of database. http://bsenduran.blogspot.com/2017/08/while-loop-in-wso2-esb.html?m=1

Comment: If I want to define a sample payload manually, like you suggested, which mediator can do that? Can you give me a sample example?

Comment: Use PayloadFactoryMediator. <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>[{"value" : 1},{"value" : 2},{"value" : 3}]</format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>

Comment: Can I use Iterate mediator inside Iterate mediator?

Comment: Yes you can https://dzone.com/articles/nested-iterator-wso2-esb

Comment: What should be the Iterate expression for the payload factory that you suggested? json-eval($.value) or just $.value?

Comment: You need to use `json-eval($.value)`

Comment: Getting error. `Exception occurred while executing the Iterate Mediator com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object with property ['value'] in path $ but found 'com.google.gson.JsonArray'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.GsonJsonProvider'.`

Comment: If you are trying to iterate through the array I have provided, then try `json-eval($)`

Comment: Facing issue in using the payload from payload factory in path parameter of back-end call. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61865247/13424730

Comment: Do you know how can this be implemented?